# ffmpeg определить качество видео

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Пишу сайт, с возможностью загрузки видео и дальнейшего конвертирования его для выбора качества.

**Сам вопрос:** можно ли при загрузке определить исходное качество видео?

**Например:** я не могу из `360р` сделать `720р`, но как узнать, что видео именно `360р`, чтобы не тратить время на дополнительное бессмысленное конвертирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам поможет [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).

> ffprobe gathers information from multimedia streams and prints it in
>   human- and machine-readable fashion.

Вам нужна секция streem.
Пример вывода:

```
$ ffprobe 123.mp4
ffprobe version N-79139-gde1a0d4 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '123.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-03-29 14:00:43
    artist          : 
    description     : 
    title           : 
  Duration: 00:00:08.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 181 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 480x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 177 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-29 14:00:49
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Comment: хороший ответ должен содержать хотя бы такую строку `ffprobe -print_format json filename.avi > info.json`.

Comment: Файл info.json пуст

Comment: да, пару параметров потерялось
` ffprobe   -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams  filename.mp4  > 1.json`